# Run Time Error Exited with error status 1

Tags: python

The problem is [this](https://www.spotify.com/nl/jobs/tech/zipfsong/) : 
I tried to solve it and I think I did too but when I mailed it for evaluation it says

```
We have tested your solution, and while doing so we unfortunately
discovered the following error:
Run Time Error

Exited with error status 1
```

Here is my code :

```
import re
import sys
def fun():
    for ind in ratio:
        max_num = ratio_list[0]
        if ratio[ind] == max_num:
            print ind

    ratio_list.remove(ratio_list[0])

hits = []
song = []   
n,m = raw_input().split(' ',1)


for i in range(0,int(n)):
    h,n = raw_input().split(" ",1)

    is_number = isinstance( int(h), int )   
    is_string = len(n)<=30 and bool(re.match('[a-z_0-9]+$', n))
    if not(is_number and is_string):
        sys.exit("Error");
    hits.append(int(h))
    song.append(n)
ratio = {}
ratio_list = []
f_of_i = hits[0]
counter = 1
index = 0

for hit in hits:
    ratio_list.append(hit*counter)
    ratio[song[index]] = hit*counter
    index = index +1
    counter = counter +1

ratio_list.sort()
ratio_list.reverse()

for j in range(0,int(m)):
    fun()
```

What am I doing wrong ? I am curious why the solution is unacceptable killing me.

Comment: I don't think the automated solution testing would provide input with `raw_input()`. They're more prone to give an input file to the program. Your program should parse it and then print output.

Comment: One thing I see is that you don't give `ratio` to the `fun()` function as a parameter. It isn't a global dictionary. Off course this probably won't fix your Run Time Error.

Comment: @Allendar it free from errors. it works.

Comment: @Bibhas I gave one other answer with `raw_input()` they accepted that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're hitting

```
    sys.exit("Error");
```

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> Some systems have a convention for assigning specific meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all other kind of errors. If another type of object is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and **any other object is printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1.**

Might be worth relaxing your input validation a little? Right now it's so strict it would reject inputs that to me appear within the spec (say if there were two spaces between the play count and the song title).

Another possibility is that your code raises an exception. On my machine this also results in an exit code of 1.

Finally, while not a bug, I think the way you reuse the variable called `n` is questionable style.

Comment: Let me try that. :D, But I need to provide a termination rule if the name of the song contains anything other than 'a-z0-9' how do you suggest I do that ?

Comment: could version be an issue ? cause on my machine its running fine. :/

Comment: @Leonidus: Yes, version could well be an issue. My advice would be to use the same version of Python they're using (2.6).

Comment: @Leonidus: I haven't read the problem statement in any detail. However, if it states that you have to reject invalid inputs, then you have to reject invalid inputs :)